# How to add custom link to the main menu

Tags: hyperlink, opencart, opencart-3

I have setup a opencart store. With the options in the category, How to add few custom links options as well?

I am using opencart version 3.0.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add that custom links in catalog/view/theme//template/common/menu.twig

add your link  tag before  tag in file.